# split not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i split decimal numbers? The variable `bidnumber` is `10.70`.

```
var bidnumber = $(this).parent('div').siblings('.advert-details').find('tr:eq(3)').find('.advert-details-col-2').attr('data-bid');
bidnumber.toString().split('.');
var first = bidnumber[0];
var second = bidnumber[1];
alert(bidnumber[0]);
second.substr(0, 1);
var finalnumber = first + '.' + second;
```

When i alert `bid[0]`, it should alert `10`.. Instead `1` is alerted. I don't get where i've gone wrong?

Comment: split works just fine - http://jsfiddle.net/dLPj3/

Comment: You have to store the result of the split method, it isn't in place.

Comment: If you want the integer part, just do `Math.floor(bidnumber)`. If you want the fraction, do `bidnumber % 1`. If you actually want both in an array, it's easier to do `[Math.floor(bidnumber), bidnumber % 1]`.

Answer (score 9):

You forgot to return the array back from `split` function:

```
bidnumber = bidnumber.toString().split('.');
```

Answer (score 1):

- The attribute value is already a string, so you don't have to convert it to a string.
- The `split` method doesn't put the array back in the variable.
- The `substr` method doesn't put the new string back in the variable.

So:

```
bidnumber = bidnumber.split('.');
var first = bidnumber[0];
var second = bidnumber[1];
second = second.substr(0, 1);
var finalnumber = first + '.' + second;
```

Or just:

```
bidnumber = bidnumber.split('.');
bidnumber[1] = bidnumber[1].substr(0, 1);
var finalnumber = bidnumber.join('.');
```

Consider also to parse the string to a number and round it:

```
var finalnumber = Math.round(parseFloat(bidnumber) * 10) / 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `split` to break apart the integer and fractional parts of a number.

For example, `10.70` when split (and converting the 70 to cents) would give a different answer to `10.7` *even though they're the **same** number*.

```
var bidnumber = 10.70;     // ignoring your DOM query for now

var whole = ~~bidnumber;   // quick and nasty 'truncate' operator
var cents = 100 * Math.abs(bidnumber - whole);
```

The final line ensures that the number of cents is positive even if the original number was negative.

The `~~` operator is actually two instances of the `~` operator, which is a bitwise "not" operator that truncates any number to a 32 bit signed value, throwing away any fractional part.  Flipping twice gives the original number, but without the fraction.

That's the easiest way to get a "round towards zero" result, as `Math.floor()` would actually give `-11` for an input of `-10.70`

Comment: For the fractional part, just take the remainder mod 1: `bidnumber % 1`.

Comment: @user973810 `Math.floor()` doesn't work properly for negative numbers, as explained in my overlapping edit.

Comment: @user973810 and neither does `n % 1` - you get a negative fraction